# consecutive event or adverb manner?

Tags: grammar

How do we recognise which of the following this sentence is ?

*The girl sat near the river, cooling her feet in the water.*

1. The girl sat near the river ***and cooled*** her feet in the water. ?
2. The girl sat near the river, ***cooling*** her feet in the water. ( in the sense of adverb manner) ( how the girl sits by the river )

Answer (score 0):

*The girl sat near the river,* [*cooling her feet in the water*].

An adjunct, but not a manner one.

The bracketed element is a gerund-participial clause functioning as a modifier in clause structure.

It is, more specifically, a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about the girl; note that is interpreted with progressive aspectuality: "the girl was cooling her feet in the water".

Another similar example is:

*Liz was lying by the pool* [*reading a novel*].

Comment: I didn't quite understand, but I drew three conclusions

Comment: 1) The girl was sitting by the river. She was cooling her feet in the water.

Comment: 2) Cooling her feet in the water, the girl sat by the river. ( manner )

Comment: 3) The girl had a seat by the river with her feet in the water for a cool-down.

Comment: No: as I said it's not a manner adjunct but a depictive one. It tells us what she was doing whilst she sat near the river.

Comment: but I also understand it as a series of successive events.

Comment: It would be better if you could explain with examples what we will analyse according to this

Comment: No: as I said it's not a manner adjunct, but a depictive one. It tells us what she was doing whilst she sat near the river. No; it doesn't convey a series of events. The sitting and the cooling are occurring simultaneously.

Comment: @emilywenly I've added a similar example to my answer.

Comment: then we can think of it as a simultaneous action, can't we?

Comment: @emilywenly That's what I said in my previous comment. The sitting and the cooling are occurring simultaneously.

Comment: You can't cool your feet by sitting near the water. You would have to be sitting by the water and have your feet in it. What's the point of grammar if the sentence doesn't make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Please notice:

This:

1. The girl **sat** near the river and **cooled** her feet in the water.

**can be compared to**:

2. The girl **sat** near [by] the river, **cooling** her feet in the water.

Please note: *sat near the river* should be *sat **by** the river* for the sentence to make more sense. You can't cool your feet in a river by sitting "near it".

The difference between 1) and 2) [with the change to by] is minor. In the first, the events are in the past and finished. They are not a series.

In the second, there is a finished action (sat) while another is described (cooling). It is a participle phrase and it modifies the girl. 2) is probably the best stylistically.

It can also be stated as: Cooling her feet in the water, the girl sat by the river.
OR
The girl, cooling her feet in the water, sat by the river.

> If a participial phrase comes at the end of a sentence, **a comma
> usually precedes the phrase if it modifies an earlier word in the
> sentence but not if the phrase directly follows the word it
> modifies.**
>
> The local residents often saw Ken wandering through the streets. (The
> phrase modifies Ken, not residents.)

[participle phrase](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html#:%7E:text=A%20participial%20phrase%20is%20a,Jack%20rushed%20to%20the%20river.)